# Rectangular collision detection

Tags: c++, algorithm, collision-detection

```
class Rectangle{
public:
   float x, y, width, height;
   // (x,y) is the lower left corner of the rectangle
};
```

Is this algorithm correct?

```
bool Rectangle::colidesWith(Rectangle other) {
   if (x+width < other.x) return false; // "other" is on the far right
   if (other.x+other.width < x) return false; //"other" is on the far left
   if (y+height < other.y) return false // "other" is up
   if (other.y+other.height < y) return false // "other" is down
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Is +ve Y up? If so, it looks ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is if the rectangles are filled (i.e. you count as collision the case in which one of them is inside the other).

Comment: You mean that if they aren't filled and one of them is inside the other then my algorithm won't work? Will it work in all the other cases?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. Also, yes for the first question.

Comment: @l19 - Your rectangles ARE filled. If one of your rectangles is inside another one then that will be counted as a collision. IF that was what you wanted then all is good. You only need to change something if that behaviour is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Yep.  You can view it as a special case of the hyperplane separation theorem which is the general version of this problem.  You are projecting these rectangles onto the X and Y axis and then checking that the resulting line segments have some separation between them.

Answer (score 0):

To me, a more intuitive way of writing this condition is:

```
( max(r1.x, r2.x) < min(r1.x+r1.w, r2.x+r2.w) ) &&
( max(r1.y, r2.y) < min(r1.y+r1.h, r2.y+r2.h) )
```

And actually this can be generalized to any dimensionality.